# Pass Model Data to Url.Action Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a DownloadExcel(List model) method in controller. I add a link in view page,

```
  @model IEnumerable<MyNameSpace.Models.Page>
  @if (Model != null)
    {

        if (Model.Count() != 0)
        {
         ....
            <div>
             <a href="@Url.Action("DownloadExcel","Home", new {model=Model})">Download Excel</a>
            </div>
         }
     }

  controller:
   public void DownloadExcel(List<Page> model)
    {

        var collection = model;
        ExcelPackage Ep = new ExcelPackage();
        ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
        ExcelWorksheet Sheet = Ep.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Report");
        Sheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "id";
        Sheet.Cells["B1"].Value = "Name";
        Sheet.Cells["C1"].Value = "Title";
        Sheet.Cells["D1"].Value = "CreatedDate";
        Sheet.Cells["E1"].Value = "CreatedBy";
        int row = 2;
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {

            Sheet.Cells[string.Format("A{0}", row)].Value = item.Id;
            Sheet.Cells[string.Format("B{0}", row)].Value = item.Name;
            Sheet.Cells[string.Format("C{0}", row)].Value = item.Title;
            Sheet.Cells[string.Format("D{0}", row)].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(item.CreatedDate);
            Sheet.Cells[string.Format("E{0}", row)].Value = item.CreatedBy;
            row++;
        }


        Sheet.Cells["A:AZ"].AutoFitColumns();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment: filename=" + "Report.xlsx");
        Response.BinaryWrite(Ep.GetAsByteArray());
        Response.End();
    }
```

How do I pass the Model data from view to controller action? It gives me a blank spreadsheet data right now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `Url.Action` in this case. `Url.Action` usually use for GET method.

In this case you can use `ajax` post as
In cshtml

```
<button onclick="download()">Download Excel</button>
```

Add script tag in cshtml page

```
function download() {
        var obj= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
       $.ajax({
           url: '@Url.Content("/Home/DownloadExcel")',
           dataType: 'json',
           type: 'POST',
           data: JSON.stringify(obj),
           contentType: 'application/json',
           success: function (data) {
               alert("success");
           }
       });
   }
```

In controller you add attribute `HttpPost` as

```
[HttpPost]
public void DownloadExcel(List<Page> model)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tested my way by using var collection = db.myTable.ToList(); I can download all data. So there is a problem with the parameter model does not receive the Model from view.

Comment: but when data is big, you can not use GET method

Comment: Tried to use POST and got 404 error when calling DownloadExcel method. Not sure why.

Comment: Reproduce your code in local, it worked when post ajax? copied same with my code yet?

Comment: "The JSON request was too large to be deserialized."